# How to find the nearest node using BFS?

Tags: python, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search, tree-traversal

Let `G(V,E)` be an undirected unweighted graph and `r` be a subset of `V`. Now node `root` is added to `G` and edges are added between `root` and all the nodes of `r`. Now for each node of `V-r` I want to find the nearest node of `r` using BFS. Please help. I have tried the following code.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def bfs(g, node):
    dist = 0
    visited = [node]
    queue = [(node, dist)]
    tr = {}
    while queue:
        s, dist = queue.pop(0)
        tr[s] = []
        for nbr in list(g.adj[s]):
            if nbr not in visited:
                visited.append(nbr)
                tr[s].append(nbr, dist+1)
                queue.append((nbr, dist+1))
    return tr

G=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(50,0.1)

r=[5,8,36,43,21]
G.add_node('root')
for i in r:
    G.add_edge(i,'root')

t = bfs(G, 'root')
print(t)
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have shown or what is your question about it? Please show a [mre] of what isn't working as expected.

Comment: I want to find nearest node of r for each node of V-r. Above code constructs the Breadh First tree of G with each node's distance from root node. @mkrieger1

Comment: I think maybe what you are looking for is Dijkstra's shortest path algo, not BFS.  What is confusing about your question is when you say 'nearest' node of r for 'each' node of V-r.  I think maybe what you mean is that, for every node in the set V-r, you want to get from r to that node with the least cost possible, yes?  In that case, you need to run Dijkstra on each pair of nodes (r, node1), (r, node2), (r, node3) and keep track of the path in a list of lists as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand the purpose of the `root` node in this problem. I think, the easiest way to solve this problem is, you call `bfs` from all the `V-r` nodes. Each time, when you able to reach a node that belongs to `r`, you return it. Because it is the first reachable node that belongs to `r`. Here is the sample of this process:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def bfs(g, node, r):
    dist = 0
    visited = [node]
    queue = [(node, dist)]
    #tr = {}
    while queue:
        s, dist = queue.pop(0)
        #tr[s] = []
        for nbr in list(g.adj[s]):
            if nbr not in visited:
                if nbr in r:
                    return (nbr, dist+1)
                
                visited.append(nbr)
                #tr[s].append((nbr, dist+1))
                queue.append((nbr, dist+1))
    #return tr
    return (NaN, NaN)

G=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(50,0.1)

r=[5,8,36,43,21]
G.add_node('root')
for i in r:
    G.add_edge(i,'root')

for n in list(G.nodes):
    if n not in r:
        t, d = bfs(G, n, r)
        print("Node {}'s nearest node in r: {} with distance: {}".format(n, t, d))
```

As `erdos_renyi` is a random graph, so it can give different result in different run. Here is a sample output:

```
Node 0's nearest node in r: 5 with distance: 2
Node 1's nearest node in r: 8 with distance: 1
Node 2's nearest node in r: 43 with distance: 2
Node 3's nearest node in r: 36 with distance: 2
Node 4's nearest node in r: 36 with distance: 2
Node 6's nearest node in r: 5 with distance: 2
Node 7's nearest node in r: 36 with distance: 2
Node 9's nearest node in r: 36 with distance: 1
Node 10's nearest node in r: 36 with distance: 2
Node 11's nearest node in r: 8 with distance: 2
Node 12's nearest node in r: 8 with distance: 3
Node 13's nearest node in r: 8 with distance: 2
Node 14's nearest node in r: 8 with distance: 2
Node 15's nearest node in r: 36 with distance: 3
Node 16's nearest node in r: 36 with distance: 3
Node 17's nearest node in r: 8 with distance: 1
Node 18's nearest node in r: 8 with distance: 1
Node 19's nearest node in r: 8 with distance: 1
Node 20's nearest node in r: 21 with distance: 1
Node 22's nearest node in r: 36 with distance: 2
Node 23's nearest node in r: 21 with distance: 2
Node 24's nearest node in r: 21 with distance: 1
Node 25's nearest node in r: 5 with distance: 1
Node 26's nearest node in r: 5 with distance: 1
Node 27's nearest node in r: 36 with distance: 3
Node 28's nearest node in r: 36 with distance: 2
Node 29's nearest node in r: 5 with distance: 1
Node 30's nearest node in r: 21 with distance: 1
Node 31's nearest node in r: 43 with distance: 1
Node 32's nearest node in r: 36 with distance: 3
Node 33's nearest node in r: 5 with distance: 2
Node 34's nearest node in r: 8 with distance: 2
Node 35's nearest node in r: 36 with distance: 2
Node 37's nearest node in r: 36 with distance: 3
Node 38's nearest node in r: 43 with distance: 1
Node 39's nearest node in r: 8 with distance: 2
Node 40's nearest node in r: 43 with distance: 1
Node 41's nearest node in r: 43 with distance: 2
Node 42's nearest node in r: 8 with distance: 2
Node 44's nearest node in r: 43 with distance: 2
Node 45's nearest node in r: 43 with distance: 2
Node 46's nearest node in r: 5 with distance: 2
Node 47's nearest node in r: 8 with distance: 1
Node 48's nearest node in r: 36 with distance: 1
Node 49's nearest node in r: 5 with distance: 2
Node root's nearest node in r: 5 with distance: 1
```

You can even further optimize this solution. First, create a list for the `V-r` nodes which will store the shortest distance to reach this nodes from `r` nodes. Initialize this list with some large (i.e., infinite) value. Now, instead of calling `bfs` for every `V-r` node, you can call bfs from all the `r` nodes and update the distance list if possible. By this process, you will make less call to `bfs` if `len(r) << len(V-r)`. I hope this solves your problem.